# XUnit Mocking Custom Identity Managers and Stores, Can not instantiate proxy of class: API.Identity.Managers.MyUserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, identity, xunit

I'm using Moq for mocking my AuthenticationController, the error happens when initializing the XUnit test,
The problem lies in the constructor of the test class on line:

```
 _myUserManager = new Mock<MyUserManager<AppUser>>(_myUserStore.Object);
```

On this line an exception of type Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException, when trying to mock the object.

and the messege and stacktrace is here:

```
Message: 
Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: API.Identity.Managers.MyUserManager`1[[API.Identity.Models.AppUser, API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
Castle.Proxies.IMyUserStoreProxy

Stack Trace: 
ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, IInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments)
Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
Mock`1.OnGetObject()
Mock.get_Object()
Mock`1.get_Object()
AuthenticateControllerTests.ctor() line 47
```

here is the test class

```
public class AuthenticateControllerTests {

    private AuthenticateController _controller;

    private Mock<ILoggerSevice> _loggerSevice;
    private Mock<IJwtAuthService> _jwtAuthService;
    private Mock<IEmailService> _emailService;
    private Mock<IEmailGateway> _emailGateway;
    private Mock<IValidationHelper> _validationHelper;

    private Mock<IMyUserStore> _myUserStore;
    private Mock<MyUserManager<AppUser>> _myUserManager;
    private Mock<IMyCustomerUserStore> _myCustomerUserStore;
    private Mock<MyCustomerUserManager<AppCustomerUser>> _myUserCustomerManager;

    private Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>> _signInManager;
    private Mock<SignInManager<AppCustomerUser>> _signInCustomerManager;

    public AuthenticateControllerTests() {
        //set up authenticate controller
        _loggerSevice = new Mock<ILoggerSevice>();
        _jwtAuthService = new Mock<IJwtAuthService>();
        _emailService = new Mock<IEmailService>();
        _emailGateway = new Mock<IEmailGateway>();
        _validationHelper = new Mock<IValidationHelper>();


        _myUserStore = new Mock<IMyUserStore>();
        _myUserManager = new Mock<MyUserManager<AppUser>>(_myUserStore.Object);
        _signInManager = new Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>>(_myUserManager.Object);

        _myCustomerUserStore = new Mock<IMyCustomerUserStore>();
        _myUserCustomerManager = new Mock<MyCustomerUserManager<AppCustomerUser>>(_myCustomerUserStore.Object);
        _signInCustomerManager = new Mock<SignInManager<AppCustomerUser>>(_myUserCustomerManager.Object);

        _controller = new AuthenticateController(_loggerSevice.Object,
                                                _jwtAuthService.Object,
                                                _myUserManager.Object,
                                                _myUserCustomerManager.Object,
                                                _signInManager.Object,
                                                _signInCustomerManager.Object,
                                                _emailService.Object,
                                                _validationHelper.Object,
                                                _emailGateway.Object);
    }
```

My custom UserManager constructor look like this:

```
    public MyUserManager(IMyUserStore myUserStore, 
                         IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
                         IPasswordHasher<AppUser> passwordHasher, 
                         IEnumerable<IUserValidator<AppUser>> userValidators, 
                         IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>> passwordValidators, 
                         ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, 
                         IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
                         IServiceProvider services, 
                         ILogger<UserManager<AppUser>> logger) : 
                    base(myUserStore, optionsAccessor,
                         passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators,
                         keyNormalizer, 
                         errors, services, logger) {

        _myUserStore = myUserStore;
    }
```

Custom user store :

```
public interface IMyUserStore : IUserStore<AppUser>, IUserEmailStore<AppUser>, 
                                IUserPhoneNumberStore<AppUser>,
                                IUserTwoFactorStore<AppUser>, IUserPasswordStore<AppUser>, 
                                IUserRoleStore<AppUser> {

public class MyUserStore : IMyUserStore {

    private readonly IUserGateway _userGateway;
    private readonly IRoleGateway _roleGateway;
```

Answer (score 0):

When mocking an implementation such as `MyUserManager`, Moq needs an accessible constructor to create the mock and you need to provide the arguments for said constructor.

So your constructor is

```
 public MyUserManager(IMyUserStore myUserStore, 
                         IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
                         IPasswordHasher<AppUser> passwordHasher, 
                         IEnumerable<IUserValidator<AppUser>> userValidators, 
                         IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>> passwordValidators, 
                         ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, 
                         IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
                         IServiceProvider services, 
                         ILogger<UserManager<AppUser>> logger)
```

but you're only providing an `IMyUserStore` argument:

```
new Mock<MyUserManager<AppUser>>(_myUserStore.Object);
```

You'll need to provide the rest of the arguments; or use a different constructor (and again provide arguments for); or better still if you can define a interface for `MyUserManager`, mock that instead.